# How can I build and train mode for Arabic word embedding from scratch using BERT and share the model on hugging face?

Tags: python, bert, topic-model

my project is (building an Arabic word embedding model). I want to build my own model on hugging face like (aubmindlab/AraBERT model) for Arabic language using Bert for word embedding.
How can I start from scratch to collect data and a pre-training model?
please, can anyone explain the steps to me?

Comment: I'm no expert but I don't understand what you want to achieve: as far as I know AraBert is already a transformer-based word embedding model, so why would you try to train new word embeddings from it?

Comment: What are steps to create model like `AraBert`

Comment: Collect lots of text in Arabic, and then train a model (see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-bert-model-from-scratch-72cfce554fc6)).

Comment: @Erwan
thanks, get it.